# Kendo Grid custom filter on date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-grid, filtering

I have seen a couple of code examples of how to do this, but none in the format I'm looking for. I tried to convert them myself, but without success. What I'm trying to do is to create a custom row filter that will give you an x-amount of options that can be used on a date.

```
columns.Bound(cc => cc.StartDate).Width(160)
   .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "startdate") })
   .Title("startdate"))
   .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Extra(false)
   .Operators(op => op.ForDate(d => d
   .IsEqualTo("At date")
   .IsLessThan("Before date")
   .IsGreaterThan("After date"))));
```

In the code above I'm trying to use filter options so a user can chose to filter events before, at and after a certain date. It would be nice if these options would actualy be shown and even better if a user could use the kendo datepicker.

So my question is: What am I doing wrong that I'm not seeing the correct options and how do i get the date-picker into the filter?

Comment: Whats the dataType of StartDate? Is it DateTime?

Comment: It could easily be converted to DateTime, but currently it's a string as that seems the easiest way to alter the value to a date instead of datetimeoffset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to have a column datatype as datetime** .
If you're using MVC, in your model, you add DataType.Date above your DatePicker property in case you want only datepicker and not datetimepicker as below:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime StartDate{ get; set; }
```

Note: add reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations if its not included in your header.

Then specify in filtrable that UI will be datetime picker

```
filterable: {
             ui: "datetimepicker"
            }
```

OR

```
columns.Bound(c => c.StartDate).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(StartDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') #")
 .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Template("DateTimeFilter")));
```

here is a sample code you can refer.In this smple there is column for Birthdate that you can refer.

[**Demo - sample**](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization)

In your case it would be like

```
columns.Bound(cc => cc.StartDate).Width(160)
   .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "startdate") })
   .Title("startdate"))
   .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Extra(false)
       .Cell(cell => cell.Template("DateTimeFilter"))
       .Operators(op => op.ForDate(d => d
       .IsEqualTo("At date")
       .IsLessThan("Before date")
       .IsGreaterThan("After date"))));
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The problem with this is that it's a HTML5/javascript type of code while i'm looking for an ASP.NET MVC solution as indicated by the code above.

Comment: The property you are binding to column must be of type date time , then kendo grid will automatically populate datetime picker in the filter section

Comment: I have tried for a bit to get this working, but it is taking me a while. By any chance, with "CreatedDate" did you mean StartDate? And how would I go about writing the template? I'm fairly new to kendo, so sorry for asking so much.

Comment: @Bloddyeye I have modified the solution please take a look

Comment: Yes, so far I understood the process. The problem is that this code would return "DateTimeFilter" not defined. That's where my question was going towards. Sorry if that was unclear from my side.